# loop through simple json object

Tags: json

how do I loop through this json object to get each item value? I know this is easy but I need to undestand why there is two brackets ([]) in the first and end of this json object.

```
[// I'm talking about this 
    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "author": "mike123",
            "postdate": "March 12, 2013 at 6:46 pm",
            "postdatecreation": "2013-03-12",
            "posteditdate": null,
            "postcontent": "eeeeee",
            "userID": 34
        }
    ]
]// and this
```

if I remove them the json still remain valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: No one can tell you why... they seem unnecessary, but since we don't know how the JSON was created, we cannot really tell you why it is an array of arrays of objects.

Comment: Hello , thanks for the answer Actually this is a result of a PHP json_encode() function . so How can I get those elements values (loop through it)?

Comment: It's all described in the question I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through your json object using $.each loop. here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ay2UB/

here results is an array of array of an object. i've passed that object by accessing index 
results[0]  will give you an array
results[0][0] will give you object

code below:

```
var results=[
    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "author": "mike123",
            "postdate": "March 12, 2013 at 6:46 pm",
            "postdatecreation": "2013-03-12",
            "posteditdate": null,
            "postcontent": "eeeeee",
            "userID": 34
        }
    ]
]

$.each(results[0][0],function(key, value){
  alert(value);
});
```

$.each can be used to loop through array or objects follow below link for more information:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Hope it helps. please correct me if I'm wrong.